# Phonegap Build app using Crosswalk crashing on Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, crosswalk

My app built with Phonegap Build and using the Crosswalk plugin is crashing after a little bit of use on Android. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening after constant Googling and debugging attempts. Any help is appreciated.

My logcat output right before and after the crash:

```
D/XWalkLib(26498): Pre init xwalk core in com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve method setValue to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve method setValue to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve method setValue to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve class class org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve method setValue to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve object class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaView to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve object class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaResourceClient to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve method setResourceClient to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve object class org.crosswalk.engine.XWalkCordovaUiClient to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve method setUIClient to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
W/ContextImpl(26498): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.foo.bar/files
W/ContextImpl(26498): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.foo.bar/cache
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve method setXWalkViewInternalVisibility to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/XWalkLib(26498): Reserve method setSurfaceViewVisibility to com.foo.bar.fooBAR
D/dalvikvm(26498): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar-1/libxwalkcore.so 0x42865d60
D/dalvikvm(26498): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar-1/libxwalkcore.so 0x42865d60
D/dalvikvm(26498): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar-1/libxwalkdummy.so 0x42865d60
D/dalvikvm(26498): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar-1/libxwalkdummy.so 0x42865d60
D/dalvikvm(26498): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar-1/libxwalkdummy.so 0x42865d60, skipping init
D/XWalkLib(26498): Post init xwalk core in com.foo.bar.fooBAR
W/ContextImpl(26498): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.foo.bar/cache
W/chromium(26498): [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/com.foo.bar-1/libxwalkcore.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
W/chromium(26498): [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar-1/libxwalkcore.so
W/chromium(26498): [WARNING:xwalk_external_extension.cc(58)] Error loading extension '/data/app-lib/com.foo.bar-1/libxwalkdummy.so': couldn't get XW_Initialize function.
W/chromium(26498): [WARNING:xwalk_extension_server.cc(412)] Failed to initialize extension: /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar-1/libxwalkdummy.so
```

And the preferences and plugins in my `config.xml` file:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application">
    <activity android:launchMode="standard" />
  </gap:config-file>

  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="handset"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>

  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />

  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>

  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="blacktranslucent" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#008b95" />

  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />

  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.1.0" />

  <platform name="android">  
    <preference name="android-versionCode" value="1" />

    <plugin name="cordova-build-architecture"      spec="https://github.com/MBuchalik/cordova-build-architecture.git#v1.0.1"     source="git" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview.git" source="git" />
    <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded" />
    <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:19+" />
  </platform>

  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"/>
  <gap:plugin name="pushwoosh-cordova-plugin" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.launchmyapp" spec="3.0" source="pgb">
    <param name="URL_SCHEME" value="mosaicties" />
  </gap:plugin>
  <plugin name="com.sharinglabs.cordova.plugin.cache" spec="1.0.0" source="pgb" />
  <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" spec="0.5.0" source="pgb" />
  <plugin name="com.virtualartifacts.webintent" spec="1.0.0" source="pgb" />
```

Any insight or help that anyone can provide would be great.

Comment: Did you try clearing the app data?

Comment: @tommybond Possible to share the code or apk for testing on device?

Comment: @AbhishekJain what do you mean clearing the app data?

Comment: @Gandhi How do you recommend I host or get an APK to you for testing? Thanks :)

Comment: @tommybond you can post the code in github

Comment: @Gandhi well I would rather just send you an APK or post one somewhere for you to access, the project is quite extensive

Comment: @tommybond ya should be fine. Just wanna debug the crash log

Comment: @tommybond: via the app's setting page on your phone.

Comment: @tommybond Since there is no update on this, i m gonna guess now. Do u have enough memory in your device while testing? Are you running any other resource intensive background process? Does this happen across all devices?

Comment: @tommybond try with another version of crosswalk, a stable one like `<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:18+" />`?

Comment: If you use crosswalk lite version, you should check this thread: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/XWALK-4884/XWALK-4884.html

Answer (score 0):

the stacktrace reads:

```
D/dalvikvm(26498): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.foo.bar-1/libxwalkdummy.so 0x42865d60, skipping init
```

this either means, that the JNI Specification within the Java source is absent and subsequently leads to the `Error loading extension` and `Failed to initialize extension` errors - or it might read `Failed to load native library` elsewhere (probably the root cause, as the error tells).

make sure that a) native assembly gets loaded with [System.loadLibrary()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html) and b) that the [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) native interface functions have been defined.

@see [Android JNI Tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) or [Crosswalk's Jira](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/XWALK-4884/XWALK-4884.html).

Comment: Do you know of a way I can ensure these things are happening using Phonegap Build? Or do you know if this is something that is on Crosswalk's end?

Comment: @tommybond try building with Android Studio or Eclipse. these JNI bindings might also be contained in a `jar` which accompanies the `so`. when both, native and java libraries are loaded, the output should look different.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck using Phonegap Build for this particular app :/

Comment: @tommybond Android Studio has a plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap, while it builds with Gradle. just use an IDE, otherwise it's no wonder to be stuck - because Java code with broken references just won't build. it seems, that you may confuse tool-chain with the IDE... because basically can build with any tool-chain. make sure to have the libs and JNIlibs referenced, then it should build the Java/Android project - while this Java project won't build, the phonegap build will fail subsequently (unless removing platform Android).

Comment: it doesn't even care if Cordova, PhoneGap or Ionic:
jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-phonegap-cordova.html

Answer (score -2):

i sugest you remove the android platform then add again. Then build again. This helped me a while ago.

Comment: This is not an answer, more like a comment.

Comment: I can't remove specific platforms and re-add them. As stated in the question title and the question text itself, I am using Phonegap Build, not Cordova or Phonegap CLI.